# Modificar css dinamicamente de elementos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una serie de `inputs` que mandan sus valores a una función para modificar el `style` de un elemento. Esto lo hago con el método `setAttribute()` el problema es que cada vez que cambia el valor el `input`, no se mantiene el estilo anterior que se le asignó en otro `input`.

```js
const $allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const $elemento = document.querySelector('.elemento')

$allInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', modifyValues)
})

function modifyValues() {
    const property = this.getAttribute("data-property")
    setCSS($elemento, property, this.value)
}

function setCSS($element, property, value) {
    $element.setAttribute('style', `${property}: ${value}px`);
}
```

```css
.elemento {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" data-property="height"/>Height
<input type="number" data-property="width"/>Width
<div class="elemento">ELEMENTO</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está pasando es que cada vez que haces `$element.setAttribute('style', '${property}: ${value}px');` estás sobreescribiendo el atributo `style` por lo que lo que todo lo que hubieses modificado antes al elemento a través de dicho atributo lo vas a perder, quedándose solamente la última modificación. Si quieres evitar eso puedes hacerlo a través de la propiedad `.style` y de la función `setProperty()` para poder pasarle unos valores encapsulados en variables.

```js
const $allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const $elemento = document.querySelector('.elemento')

$allInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', modifyValues)
})

function modifyValues() {
    const property = this.getAttribute("data-property")
    setCSS($elemento, property, this.value)
}

function setCSS($element, property, value) {
    $element.style.setProperty(property, value + "px");
}
```

```css
.elemento {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" data-property="height"/>Height
<input type="number" data-property="width"/>Width
<div class="elemento">ELEMENTO</div>
```